# When a woman's husband dies and she remarries, which husband will she be with in Jannah?

Tags: jannah, husband-wife

When a woman's husband dies and she marries another man; with whom she shall be in Jannah, with her first husband or second husband?

Answer (score 3):

The Prophet Muhammad (SAWS) said:

> قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم : المرأة لآخر أزواجها
>
> *Allah’s Messenger (pbuh) said: ‘In the Paradise,] a woman will be with* **her last husband**.’
>
> <sup>-Tabaqaat Abu Shaikh p.270. Albani classified it as Sahih in Silsala Sahiha H. 1281</sup>

In this hadith, it **clearly states that a woman would be with her last husband.**

[Huzaifa](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudhayfah_ibn_al-Yaman) (Prophet's Companion) said to his wife,

> قال حذيفة لامرأته إن أردت أن تكوني زوجتي في الجنة فلا تزوجي بعدي فإن المرأة لآخر أزواجها ، ولذلك حرم الله تعالى على أزواج رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم أن يتزوجن بعده
>
> *'If you wish to be my wife in the Heaven do not marry anyone after me for* **a woman will be with last of his husbands and for this reason [Allah forbade it for the wives of the Messenger (pbuh) to remarry after him](https://quran.com/33/53).**'
>
> <sup>-Mushkil Al-Athaar 2/147 Hadith 552</sup>

The statement, *['Allah forbade it for the wives of the Messenger (pbuh) to remarry after him'](https://quran.com/33/53)* is mentioned in the Qu'ran:

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آَمَنُوا....وَمَا كَانَ لَكُمْ أَنْ تُؤْذُوا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ وَلَا أَنْ تَنْكِحُوا أَزْوَاجَهُ مِنْ بَعْدِهِ أَبَدًا إِنَّ ذَلِكُمْ كَانَ عِنْدَ اللَّهِ عَظِيمً
>
> *"O ye who believe! …* **Nor is it right for you that** *ye should annoy Allah's Messenger, or that* **ye should marry his widows after him at any time.** *Truly such a thing is in Allah's sight an enormity."*
>
> <sup>[- Quran 33:53](https://quran.com/33/53)</sup>

**The best view on this is that a woman will be with her last husband in Jannah.**

Other views have hadith which are **weak or ignored**. See [this](https://islamqa.info/en/8068).

And Allah knows best.